# Nginx Version + AWK Not Working

Tags: awk

Today I've noticed that I can't use "awk" on "nginx -v".

I've tried running this command: `nginx -v | awk -F/ '{print $2}'`

This should of been output like this: `nginx/1.4.3`

But instead it gives me `nginx version: nginx/1.4.3`

Any idea why it would behave this way !?

Also you can't output it to file by running: `nginx -v > file.txt`

Comment: In fact `python -V` behaves same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nginx` must be writing that message to standard error, not standard output. If you want to pipe it, you have to redirect stderr to stdout:

```
nginx -v 2>&1 | awk -F/ '{print $2}'
```

Comment: You're right :-) This worked for me `nginx -v 2>&1 | awk '{print $3}'`